# Picklist value inside Custom Label

Tags: lightning-web-components, picklist, customlabel, global-picklist

Hello I was wondering if I can save several values in one custom label.
Because I have a global picklist value set but I only want to use some of them (but I cannot deactivate those values because they are used in other objects). For example I want to save 'a','b','c' (values from the global picklist) in a custom label to use this label in a LWC combobox.
Does anybody has any idea if this is possible? And if it is how do I do it?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't. 
Why not just create another picklist?
As an option, you can save picklist data in Custom Label or some Metadata record as JSON and parse it in the LWC.